# Not work git in terminal

Tags: git, terminal

I try used git. But terminal write:

```
    ROUTER-SETTINGS:~ ILOVEME1199$ git
git: error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git' (errno=No such file or directory)
```

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/666090/141

Comment: Just as an FYI: Users on StackOverflow expect that you outline your problem in a clear way and help us help you solve it. When asking questions about git, it's quite helpful to outline whether you have installed `git`, whether this behavior has changed for some reason and also showing output like `git --version`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you have `git` in your path (or possibly installed at all). It can be confusing on OS X, so here is [the best resource](https://superuser.com/questions/666086/issues-installing-git-under-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks). Quoting the answer:

> > Just download the [original git package][1]. The installer will install git under `/usr/local/git` (you need to deactivate security
> >     options to run the installer).
>
> There is a preinstalled git wrapper in `/usr/bin` used by Xcode which
>   does not work without installing Xcode. You need to run
>   `/usr/local/git/bin/git` explicit or change the PATH variable to
>   contain `/usr/local/git/bin` before `/usr/bin`!
>
> Create/edit your `~/.profile` with the following:
>
> ```
> PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
> export PATH
> ```
>
> [1]: http://git-scm.com/download/mac